# Bash getopts error handling

Tags: bash, getopts

This is an error I encountered when playing with Getopts. The following is the code snippet I have been playing simply listen to 3 options when executing a script.

```
while getopts "vcn" opt; do
  case $opt in
     v) echo "Print V" ;;
     c) echo "Print C" ;;
     n) echo "Print N" ;;
     *) echo "Invalid Option" && exit 1 ;;
  esac 
done
```

I'm not sure Why I'm getting the below error when executing this script even though I have handled errors with *) option to do so.
The error handle is working as shown in the picture below but after getting an unprogrammed error.

[image: The Error msg on the terminal]

Comment: Have you read the manual page for `getopts`? The `"vcn"` lists the options that are valid. You have two choices for the error handling, depending on if the first character in the option string is a `:` or not. Frankly the error message from getopts is better than yours. The `*` happens to work in your code as it happens to match `?`, not because it matches `a`.

In general it is much more helpful to post text rather than screenshots.

Comment: What does the text in the image say? Please copy and paste it as text into your question so it's readable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the [reference manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bourne-Shell-Builtins.html#index-getopts):

> `getopts` can report errors in two ways. If the first character of *optstring* is a colon, silent error reporting is used. **In normal operation, diagnostic messages are printed when invalid options or missing option arguments are encountered.**
>
> **If an invalid option is seen, `getopts` places `?` into *name* and, if not silent, prints an error message and unsets `OPTARG`.** If `getopts` is silent, the option character found is placed in `OPTARG` and no diagnostic message is printed.

In your case, *optstring* is `vcn`, so `getopts` prints an error message itself. To disable that, use `getopts :vcn` instead.

Also, your:

> ```
> echo "Invalid Option" && exit 1
> ```

Should be:

```
echo>&2 "Invalid Option"; exit 1
```

That is:

- errors should go to standard error (file descriptor 2), not standard output.
- And you should exit unconditionally, not only if `echo` succeeds.